# How can I reference a URL in Django settings.py

Tags: django

I'm trying to reference a url in my settiings.py file.
I currently have this in my urls.py file

```
from django.urls import (
    path,
    reverse_lazy,
    re_path
)
     my_app = 'accounts'

     re_path(
            r'^reset_password_confirm/(?P<uidb64>[0-9A-Za-z_-]+)-(?P<token>.+)/$',
            PasswordResetConfirmView.as_view(
                success_url = reverse_lazy('accounts:password_reset_complete')
             ),
            name = 'password_reset_confirm',
            ),
```

and I have this in my settings.py file

```
LOGIN_EXEMPT_URLS =( 
                    'accounts/login/',
                    'accounts/register/',
                    'accounts/',
                    'accounts/reset_password/',
                    'accounts/reset_password_done/',
                    r'^accounts/reset_password_confirm/(?P<uidb64>[0-9A-Za-z_-]+)-(?P<token>.+)/$',
                    'accounts/password_reset_complete/',
                    )
```

this is my custom login middleware

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.shortcuts import redirect,render
from django.urls import reverse


EXEMPT_URLS = settings.LOGIN_EXEMPT_URLS     

class LoginRequired:

    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response

    def __call__(self,request):
        response = self.get_response(request)
        return response

    def process_view(self, request, view_func, view_args, view_kwargs,):
        assert hasattr(request, 'user')
        path = request.path.lstrip('/')

        url_is_exempt = any(path==url for url in EXEMPT_URLS)

        if request.user.is_authenticated and url_is_exempt:
            if path == reverse('accounts:homepage').lstrip('/'):
                return None
            return redirect(settings.LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL)

        elif request.user.is_authenticated or url_is_exempt:
            return None

        else:
            return redirect(settings.LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL)
```

I think my major problem is with the

```
"r'^accounts/reset_password_confirm/(?p<uidb64>[0-9A-Za-z_-]+)-(?p<token>.+)/$'"
```

because the others seems to work

Comment: try by removing `^` and `$` from url `r'^accounts/reset_password_confirm/(?p<uidb64>[0-9A-Za-z_-]+)-(?p<token>.+)/$'`

Comment: I tried it now but it didn't work. but do you know if the regular expression is right in the  "r'^accounts/reset_password_confirm/(?p<uidb64>[0-9A-Za-z_-]+)-(?p<token>.+)/$'" ?

Comment: can you please add error that you are facing with your question?

Comment: the logic of the program is to restrict users from accessing some pages in the website by redirecting them to the homepage execept the LOGIN_EXEMPT_URLS.   Any time i try to get the url, it redirects me to the homepage

Comment: if all URLs are working then try by removing regex form URL `accounts/reset_password_confirm/`

Comment: it is still not working. i'm actually trying to go to this url http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/reset_password_confirm/Ng-53h-f41c3effef0cf0c68ceb/.  maybe this will help get the error

Comment: Are you using a custom middleware or third-party library that makes use of LOGIN_EXEMPT_URLS? It's not a standard part of Django.

Comment: its a custom middleware @DanielRoseman

Comment: Well, please can you show it then.

Comment: i just edited the post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I have finally figured it out. the problem is with the custom login middleware
process view function. I should have imported the 're' module and done this instead

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.shortcuts import redirect,render
from django.urls import reverse
import re

EXEMPT_URLS = [re.compile(url) for url in settings.LOGIN_EXEMPT_URLS]     

class LoginRequired:

    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response

    def __call__(self,request):
        response = self.get_response(request)
        return response

    def process_view(self, request, view_func, view_args, view_kwargs,):
        assert hasattr(request, 'user')
        path = request.path_info.lstrip('/')

        url_is_exempt = any(url.match(path) for url in EXEMPT_URLS)

        if request.user.is_authenticated and url_is_exempt:
            if path == reverse('accounts:homepage').lstrip('/'):
                return None
            return redirect(settings.LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL)

        elif request.user.is_authenticated or url_is_exempt:
            return None

        else:
            return redirect(settings.LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL).
```

the major aspect is the

```
EXEMPT_URLS = [re.compile(url) for url in settings.LOGIN_EXEMPT_URLS]
```

and

```
url_is_exempt = any(url.match(path) for url in EXEMPT_URLS)
```

with this i would be able to match the urls